# Set a scheduling task (Windows Hosting) in Parallels Plesk Panel

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks

I need to set a scheduling task (Windows Hosting). I configured like below

```
Path to executable file = C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5\php.exe

Arguments = C:\Inetpub\vhosts\example.com\httpdocs\accompalive\Scheduler.php
```

Accompalive is the root folder name and aspiresoftwareconsultancy is the domain name. I tried with example.com also as domine name but schedular is not running. I set each 2 minutes every hour, day, week, month, year as timing. I also set one notification email address. But I am getting email with an error file having message `"Could not open input file: C:\Inetpub\vhosts\aspiresoftwareconsultancy.tld\httpdocs\accompalive\Scheduler.php"`. Did I set it correctly or need some changes? thank you.

Comment: well, aspire is included in my name :)

Comment: What makes you think that the problem is related to scheduler? Are you sure there is nothing wrong with your scheduler script?

Comment: I have tested manually on my server by whole path and I am getting correct output. I just want schedular task to run that file.

Comment: Thanks, I solved this by replacing "aspiresoftwareconsultancy.tld" with "aspiresoftwareconsultancy.com"

Answer (score 0):

This is almost a year now.

But As there is no answer to this question, Here is what I've found:

If the script can be executed with an interpreter (e.g., PHP or Perl) and does not require parameters defined in an HTTP request, create a new scheduled task that calls the script interpreter with the path to the script as an option

You can do it like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\php\bin\php.exe <path to your php script> <input file>output file 2>&1
```

For More See: http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/115292

Hope it helps :).

Answer (score 0):

I used your code and it is working for me.

```
Path to executable file = C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP4\php.exe
Arguments = C:\Inetpub\vhosts\example.com\httpdocs\accompalive\Scheduler.php
```

If you have validation on `scheduler.php` or wrong code then it can not work.

When I send some data using get method (like `Arguments = C:\Inetpub\vhosts\example.com\httpdocs\accompalive\Scheduler.php?id=12`) then I also got text file(utility output) in email where they said that `"Could not open input file"`.